# Swift - Change SKSpriteNode texture using an array of textures

Tags: arrays, swift, skspritenode, sktexture

I am trying to animate a SKSpriteNode using an array of textures. What I am trying to achieve is to iterate through the texture array and change the SKSpriteNode texture through each iteration and display it's change for about 1 second. The only problem is, the loop is continuing as the animations are taking place I believe, so I can't see the changes.

I essentially want to be able to see each texture on the screen for about a second or two before it changes. Here is what I have so far.

```
var textures: [SKTexture] = [texture1, texture2, texture3, texture4]
var sprite = SKSpriteNode()

func animateSpriteTextures() {

    for texture in textures {
    /* Want to pause for about a second or two here, but does not. */
    sprite.texture = texture

    let scaleDown = SKAction.scaleTo(200, duration: 1)
    let scaleUp = SKAction.scaleTo(300, duration: 1)
    sprite.runAction(SKAction.sequence([scaleDown, scaleUp]))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `animateWithTextures:` action. You could do something like:

```
sprite.runAction(SKAction.animateWithTextures(textures, timePerFrame: 1.0))
```

If you need to change the size of the sprite as the animation occurs, then you'll probably want to create an action group `SKAction.group()` to coordinate the animation and the size changes or maybe `animateWithTextures:timePerFrame:resize:restore:` would work for you.